# Refresh cached product images programmatically

Tags: magento-1, cache, product-images, product-collection

After flushing image cache, cached product images are rebuild when they are loaded from frontend like from product view page ...

I need them restored w/o vistit every page manuall, so how to this in an efficent way?

I needed a fast solution and just came up with, to "simulate" page view ...

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(3,4))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$ids = $collection->getAllIds();

$func = function($id) {
    return 'http://domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/' . $id;
};

$urls = array_map($func, $ids);
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

I know i could make it store view based to reduce URL count ... but is there a method to generate cached images without using `file_get_contents`?

Comment: As per the helper used in templates I'm not too sure about whether this can be achieved in a nice way (`<img ... src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>" ... />` - I think you would need to generate each image size for each "type" manually this way?). As your question just came to my mind yesterday at one point I was playing around a bit but I wasn't able to get an image created in the cache folder by that helper. Maybe you're one step ahead already anyway? Interesting question so I though about checking once ;)

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner not tried further ... just think about getting images from `catalog_product_entity` (?), add pathes and store them in predefined size.

Comment: I might be wrong, but some part of the directory structure would still be missing I guess? I.e. `media/catalog/products/cache/`randomstring`/100x/A/b/Abc.jpg` - I think that topic will require quite some testing